# Why can't I insert an image into php?

Tags: php, html, image, filemaker

trying to insert an image into some php. This code pulls from the database thumbnail page to show an item's details. It works fine when it's text "see it in 3d view" but when I try to insert a premade image in that location instead (a button jpg, aka "img src="#"), I'm getting an error. How can I do this correctly? Still learning the ins and outs of php and html, they don't always play the way I expect them to. Thanks for any help.

```php
echo ("<br><img src= \"");
echo ($thumbnail);
echo (" \"><br><br><a href = \"");
echo ($photo);
echo ("\"><b>See it in 360 view</b></a></div>");
echo ("<div id=\"info\"; style=\"width:45%\"><br><br><div class = \"date\">");
echo ($date);
echo ("</div><br>");
echo ("<div class = \"blurbs\">");
echo ($sub);
echo ("<br><br><br>");
echo ($desc);
echo ("<br><br>");
echo ($hist);
echo ("<br><br><br><b>Provenance:</b><br>");
echo ($prov);
echo ("<br><br><b>Construction Label:</b><br>");
echo ($labl);
echo ("<br><br><br><br><b>");
echo ($cNum);
echo ("</b>");
```

Comment: Could You show (or look at) code generated by PHP?

Comment: You're outputting a space between the thumbnail name and the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="#">` would never work. `src="#"` is a shortcut for "current page". e.g. browsers will try to use the current page's URL as the source for the image, which means it'll be trying to load a bunch of HTML as if it was a jpg/gif/png image. Since html isn't any of those, it'll just be a flat-out "this image contains errors" error.

Whatever you're putting in `$thumbnail` needs to be a proper url, e.g.

```
<img src="kittens.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/kittens.jpg">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echp base64_encode(file_get_contents('kittens.jpg')); ?>">
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using # as shorthand for the actual link, hadn't realized what hashtag actually stood for here.

Answer (score 1):

I would start out with cleaning up your file and remove some of  the unneeded overhead (I personally love to have my controllers (Which is generating the output for my view files)

What is the output of this PHP file and what did you expect it to be?

```
<br><img src="<?= $thumbnail ?>">
<br><br><a href="<?= $photo ?>"><b>See it in 360 view</b></a>
</div>
<div id="info" style="width:45%"><br><br><div class = "date">
 <?= $date ?>
</div><br>
<div class="blurbs">
 <?= $sub ?>
<br><br><br>
<?= $desc ?> 
<br><br>
<?= $hist ?>
<br><br><br><b>Provenance:</b><br>
<?= $prov ?>
<br><br><b>Construction Label:</b><br>
<?= $labl ?>
<br><br><br><br><b>
<?= $cNum ?>
</b>
```

a note to this is that Short Open tag which is enabled by default from PHP 5.4)

You should also look into using div or p tags instead of all the line breaks (it makes it easier for you to make changes to later on)

Comment: SO what this is supposed to do is pull an image linked to the thumbnail on the previous page and populate the page with information from the archive database, which is does correctly. I really just want to replace the text saying "see it in 260" with a custom button I built...

Comment: what is $thumbnail, have you looked in your browser to confirm it's an actual image?

Comment: ....yes. Everything else works, I'm asking a very specific question here, how can I insert a single, unrelated jpg into a page full of php? (It's a for loop, it goes through every dress in the database and allows the thumbnail to link to a page full of detail information.) Asking if the rest of the code works is not helpful!

Comment: as asked the link in $thumbnail is a real image you have seen in the browser.
I'm asking a very specific question to help you solve your issue, if it doesn't show a image, it might be because you are not pulling the right link

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. But yes, the $thumbnail is a real image for each directory item. That's showing up fine. I want to insert an external image into the description, instead of plain text, where "see it in 360 view" is listed.  I tried to insert the image alone, which it didn't like, then broke the php with:  ?> <img src= "blahblah.jpg"> <?php  which it didn't like either

Comment: In the code i provided it shouldn't be a problem to just change the 
<b>See it in 360 view</b>
to a img tag instead.